# How to install pymatgen for Python 2.7.x and not 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda, pymatgen

The pymatgen module is supposed to work for Python 2.7.x or 3.  Files for both are available (https://anaconda.org/matsci/pymatgen/files).  My Python (sys.version) is 2.7.11.

I tried installing with standard: `"conda install -c mastic pymatgen"`, but it returns an error:

```
"Fetching package metadata ...........                                                                       
Solving package specifications: .                                                                           

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:                              
  - pymatgen -> python 3.6*                                                                                 
  - python 3.5*                                                                                             
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package."
```

It looks like it is trying to install the pymatgen module for Python 3 and I am a version short.

I want to install the 2.7.x compatible version, but can't find instructions on how to force the conda install to do that.

I can't upgrade to 3.6 for other reasons.

Comment: I think this guide may help https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html#use-a-different-version-of-python

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pip ?

But first install `NumPy` as they mentioned [Here](http://pymatgen.org/#pip)

then use : `pip install pymatgen`

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted from running Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh, instead of  Miniconda2-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever conda you installed, you can create a specific Python 2.7 environment using

```
conda create --name py27 python=2.7
```

You should then be able to follow all the steps for Python 2.7 install.